# Как сделать Background

Tags: html, css, background

Добрый день!
Подскажите как можно реализовать такой background. Необходимо чтобы при уменьшении экрана правая часть bg масштабировалась.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю вот так:

```css
background-color: #F2F6FF;
background-image: url(../../public/images/bg/slider.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 100% 0;
```

и ничего не выходит

Comment: Вопрос задан слишком абстрактно. У Вас есть цветной фон, справа изображение какое-то и это изображение должно увеличиваться при уменьшении экрана или оно просто должно сохранять свой размер вплоть до пропорций мобильного разрешения?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю и `background-image` у вас только правая часть, то можно так ՝background-size: cover;՝. Я думаю так получится.

Comment: Прошу прощения за абстрактность. Вот по этой ссылке http://prntscr.com/gnt7dx изображение при размере экрана свыше 960px, По этой http://prntscr.com/gnt81y меньше 960px. В дальнейшем этот блок будет использоваться на других страница и будет меняться только центральная картинка (человек с ноутбуком).

Comment: cover ничего хорошего не дает